# Vuex rest api consuming for scale

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I am building an application which consumes an API. 
I'd like to be able to make a module builder with prefixed actions, and mutations, and also middleware for async operations, so I can easily expand the application.

I built a prototype, but it feels like it is a draft and I am not sure it if follows flux pattern correctly. For example, my action types are not UPPERCASE

```
const defaultState = {
  [LOADING]: false,
  [DATA]: null,
  [ERRORS]: null,
};

const makeModule = moduleActions => ({
  namespaced: true,
  state: { ...defaultState },
  mutations: {
    fetch(state) {
      state[LOADING] = true;
      state[ERRORS] = null;
    },
    setData(state, data) {
      state[LOADING] = false;
      state[DATA] = data;
      state[ERRORS] = null;
    },
    setErrors(state, errors) {
      state[LOADING] = false;
      state[ERRORS] = errors;
    },
  },
  actions: moduleActions,
});

export {
  makeModule,
};
```

After I construct my store using it:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    [namespaces.cars]: makeModule({
      async getCars({ commit }) {
        commit('fetch');
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

For react/redux I use [reduxsauce](https://github.com/infinitered/reduxsauce) which is working great for me.

I tired finding something similar for Vuex, but with no luck. Can you recommend some best practices to follow, or a library that does this for you?

Thanks